# How to make an Android app that can edit MP3 files?

Tags: android, mp3, edit

I want to make an app that downloads a specific MP3 file, allow the user to crop/trim it and re-upload it back to our server. How can I trim MP3 files inside my app ? Do I need to achieve this in C and then port it/use NDK ? If MP3 is tough, I can switch over to other easy formats too.

Will be great if anyone can show me the right path.

Comment: --> RIGHT PATH

peace, just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

I think of all the alternatives, using something like [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) and compiling for the NDK is your best option.  Be warned that there are patent restrictions on the MP3 format (most of which I don't understand), and you may run into problems if you distribute your app.  YMMV

Comment: Thanks. Any other music format that you can think of which doesn't get me into any sort of licensing issues ?

Comment: Ogg Vorbis or WAV should be fine.  There are probably a few more, but those are the most common.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it on Android yet, but there is a [pure Java MP3 decoder / player](http://code.google.com/p/mp3transform/) I wrote a while ago. Maybe you can use parts of it. The code is based on JLayer from JavaZoom (also LGPL).

Answer (score 0):

This library helps to trim MP3,AAC/MP4,WAV,3GPP/AMR...

http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/